# document type does not allow element "div" here; missing one of "object", "ins", "del", "map", "button" start-tag

Tags: html

W3C validation is giving me the above error on the following on the line:

```
<div id='main' style='border:1px solid #999;'>
```

in the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><body>
<p>
    <label for="wrap">Quick Reference:</label>
    <div id='main' style='border:1px solid #999;'>
        <div id='wrap' ></div>
    </div>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are your <!DOCTYPE><html><body> tags? You know what correct html structure is?

Comment: A `<div>` *cannot* be a child of a `<p>` element.

Comment: Yes but when I remove the <p> elements I get this error: document type does not allow element "label" here; missing one of "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "pre", "address", "fieldset", "ins", "del" start-tag

Comment: My doctype, html and body tags are there. I just didn't include them for clarity.

Comment: You're saying that the only things you're *not* showing us, are the wrapping `<body>` and `<html>` elements? And the preceding `<!DOCTYPE>`? I'd suggest including your full HTML because what you've posted is invalid HTML (due to the `<div>` being wrapped within a `<p>`), but if the error persists then it suggests something else is going wrong as well.

Comment: You can always put your closing `</p>` tag and then insert your `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a div inside a paragraph, and the content you do have doesn't look like a paragraph. Replace the `p` with `div` (which is a generic block level container for when a more suitable element does not exist in HTML).

Additionally, labels label *form controls* not divs. You probably should have a heading (possibly an `h1` but more likely `h2` if there was more context) not a `label`. Headings also cannot appear inside paragraphs.